# Javascript slideshow troubleshooting

Tags: javascript, slideshow

I am creating a Javascript slideshow for my company, but after writing the code my images are not showing. The goal of this slide show is to be expandable, so that i can add more images if needed. I am also going to be switching out the previous and next HTML hyperlinks for buttons. Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

```
<html>
<head>

<script language="JavaScript">

var interval = 1500;
var random_display = 0;
var imageDir = "v/vspfiles/templates/133/images/template/";

var imageNum = 0;

imageArray = new Array();
imageArray[imageNum++] = new imageItem(imageDir + "091814_banner.jpg");
imageArray[imageNum++] = new imageItem(imageDir + "0914_Banner1.jpg")
imageArray[imageNum++] = new imageItem(imageDir + "0914_Banner-1_v2.jpg")
imageArray[imageNum++] = new imageItem(imageDir + "navigation_background_left2.png")

var totalImages = imageArray.length;

function imageItem(image_location){
  this.image_item = new Image();
  this.image_item.src = image_location;
}

function get_ImageItemLocation(imageObj){
  return(imageObj.image_item.src);
}

function randNum(x,y){
  var range = y - x + 1;
  return Math.floor(Math,random() * range) + x;
}

function get_NextImage() {
  if(random_display){
    imageNum = randNum(0,totalImages-1);
}
  else{
    imageNum = (imageNum + 1) % totalImages;
}
  var new_image = get_ImageItemLocation(imageArray[imageNum]);
  return (new_image);
}

function get_PrevImage(){
  imageNum = (imageNum-1) % totalImages;
  var new_image = get_ImageItemLocation(imageArray[imageNum]);
  returns(new_image);
}

function prevImage(place){
  var new_image = get_PrevImage();
  document[place].src = new_image;
}

function switchImage(place) {
  var new_image = get_NextImage();
  document[place].src = new_image;
  var recur_call = "switchImage('"+place+"')";
  timerID = setTimeout(recur_call,interval);
}



</script>

</head>

<body onLoad="switchImage('slideImg')">
<img name="slideImg" src="DSC09890.JPG" width=500 height=375 border=0>
<a href="#" onClick="switchImage('slideImg')">play slide show</a>
<a href="#" onClick="clearTimeout(timerID)"> pause</a>
<a href="#" onClick="prevImage('slideImg'); clearTimeout(timerID)"> previous</a>
<a href="#" onClick="switchImage('slideImg'); clearTimeout(timerID)">next </a>

</body>
</html>
```

*edit*

The slide show is now working properly. Since it is now working, I am looking into creating buttons for the controls rather then hyperlinks. I am planning on doing this with a slideshow Div. I am unsure however how to edit the CSS and HTML to make the buttons appear on top of the slideshow and stay in exact locations.

*Update*

I have solved the how to create the buttons. My previous button is not working however. All of the other buttons are.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a more detailed description of the problem. Do the images rotate but not load? Errors in the console?

Comment: and also provide a fiddle

Comment: @isherwood The first part of the problem was corrected; I was referencing the photos locally when I needed to retrieve them from a server.

Comment: @anni Sorry, I am not sure what you mean exactly.

Comment: @isherwood http://jsfiddle.net/ghmjjbvr/       Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Sure, but you've accepted an answer, so there's probably no point. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about simplifying the input for your code first, and then rewriting it accordingly?
Assuming all images are in the same location, a good starting point would be to create an array containing only the images names:

(disclaimer: I did not test this code, it may contain syntax errors, consider it pseudo-code)

```
var images = ["image1.png","image2.jpg"];
```

Assuming you only are showing one image at a time on a page, you can keep a global variable around containing the index being shown.

```
var currentImage = 0; //starting image
var imageElement = document.getElementById("slideImg") //put this in the id instead of 'name'
```

Accordingly, you can re-use the same < img > tag on the page, all you need to do is re-point it's image tag.

```
function navigate(direction) {
    switch(direction){
//using modulo and adding the length of the array, we ensure we get positive offsets within the array.
    case "back" : currentimage = (currentImage-- +images.length)%images.length;
    case "forward" :  (currentImage++ +images.length)%images.length;
}
 imageElement.src = images[currentImage];
}
```

Now you should be able to call the navigate function from within the onclick of elements you add on the page to perform navigations. Similarly, you should be able to call it from within your timer.

Comment: Thank You Joeppie. I was able to implement your pseudo-code successfully and in the process caught my mistake that was preventing the images from showing. I was running this as a local directory for the picture when I needed to run it from a server. Thanks. I am now trying to make the buttons for the slideshow. Is there a way of usiing CSS or HTML to make the links: next slide, previous slide, pause, play actual buttons on the slide show?

Comment: CSS indeed as transitions these days, I suggest googling, I have a train to catch. Glad to be of service :)